# Select ALL MAX dates for the same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created the row number over partition by ID for a table. I would like to select MAX dates for each ID, but some MAX dates are the same and I would like to select them as well. How can I achieve this selection?

Original Table:

| ROW_NUM | EMP_ID | EMP_ID2 | ID | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 568 | 444 | 4220 | 11-25-2020 |
| 2 | 568 | 501 | 4220 | 11-25-2020 |
| 3 | 569 | 443 | 4220 | 11-01-2020 |
| 4 | 510 | 501 | 4220 | 11-12-2020 |
| 1 | 550 | 411 | 4221 | 12-25-2020 |
| 2 | 568 | 520 | 4221 | 12-25-2020 |
| 3 | 410 | 415 | 4221 | 12-25-2020 |
| 4 | 510 | 591 | 4221 | 11-12-2020 |
| 1 | 954 | 345 | 4225 | 09-25-2020 |
| 2 | 568 | 520 | 4225 | 09-25-2020 |
| 3 | 400 | 789 | 4225 | 09-25-2020 |
| 4 | 510 | 554 | 4225 | 09-25-2020 |
| 5 | 210 | 801 | 4225 | 05-12-2020 |

Table after selection:

| ROW_NUM | EMP_ID | EMP_ID2 | ID | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 568 | 444 | 4220 | 11-25-2020 |
| 2 | 568 | 501 | 4220 | 11-25-2020 |
| 1 | 550 | 411 | 4221 | 12-25-2020 |
| 2 | 568 | 520 | 4221 | 12-25-2020 |
| 3 | 410 | 415 | 4221 | 12-25-2020 |
| 1 | 954 | 345 | 4225 | 09-25-2020 |
| 2 | 568 | 520 | 4225 | 09-25-2020 |
| 3 | 400 | 789 | 4225 | 09-25-2020 |
| 4 | 510 | 554 | 4225 | 09-25-2020 |

Thank you.

Comment: I tried "ROWNEMBER OVER PARTITION" like this : SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE) ROW_NUM , MYTABLE.* FROM MYTABLE

Comment: use `DENSE_RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: I was testing the answers. Thank you @Dale K.

Comment: OMG , I'm sorry. I will accept the answers. I'm new to this site. Thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY DATE DESC) rnk
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ROW_NUM, EMP_ID, EMP_ID2, ID, DATE
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always join to a subquery:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table t
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, MAX(date) AS max_date FROM my_table GROUP BY 1) subq
    ON subq.id = t.id
WHERE t.date = subq.max_date
ORDER BY t.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `rank` instead:

```
select * from (
   select rank() over (partition by id order by date desc) rn
   from tablename
) t where rn = 1;
```